# RemoteWebDriver with Edge Chromium 86/87 hangs with EdgeDriver.merge()

Tags: java, selenium, grid, microsoft-edge, remotewebdriver

Selenium: 3.141.59;
Chromium Edge: Version 87.0.664.41 (Official build) (64-bit);
hub runs on linux, nodes on Windows 10.

I Would like to set up the RemoteWebDriver with Chromium Edge version 87. I have tried various options, and I am currently most successful with:

```
   ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe");
   EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions().merge(options);
   RemoteWebDriver drv = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(globalSetting.getHubUrl()),
                        edgeOptions);
   drv.get("http://www.google.com");
```

With this the edge browser starts, but is unable to connect to the google url, because it is stuck in RemoteDriver setup. After some time, I get the a timeout and the message: `WebDriverException: unknown error: unrecognized Chrome version: Edg/87.0.664.41`

[With Chrome (google) it works fine.]

I red somewhere that this merge is not working with newer Chromium Edge and EdgeOptions should be used instead. But I only found Python code and it uses a field which EdgeOption in Java does not have (options.useChromium = true).

Has anybody been successful with Chromium Edge 86/87 and RemoteWebDriver in Java? If so could you provide a code example?

Comment: Instead of using ChromeOptions(), I suggest you only try to make a test by adding the EdgeOptions(). See whether your automation code works or not.

Comment: With only: EdgeIOptions eo = new EdgeOptions()? That would lead to -> Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities {browserName: MicrosoftEdge}

Comment: I suggest you make a test with the code mentioned in [this link](https://justpaste.it/3g3rk) and let us know whether it works or not.